# Core Data Multiple ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, nsmanagedobjectcontext, managedobjectcontext

How the multiple ManagedObjectContext (MOC) works in core data(Swift 2, iOS 9). I have been through lots of links & material online and answers on StackOverflow, but couldn't find exact answer.

I want to know, suppose I have created main MOC which points to PersistentStoreCoordinator (PSC)and another private queue MOC which has parent context set to above mentioned main MOC.

Question 1: Then How this works ? Is the hierarchy built like this : Private queue MOC --> Main queue MOC --> PSC.

Question 2: If I call save on 'private queue MOC', will it save to main MOC and in turn automatically main MOC will save to PSC ? or After save on Private MOC we have to call explicit save on Main MOC to save it to PSC ?

I just started working on core data and online links are not so clear. So, any simplified explanation will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, the hierarchy is however you create it. If you create a context with no parent, and then another one whose parent context is the first context, it'll be as you describe.

For question 2 I'll turn to the [documentation on NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext):

> When you save changes in a context, the changes are only committed “one store up.” If you save a child context, changes are pushed to its parent. Changes are not saved to the persistent store until the root context is saved.

Saving is **never** automatic, so the parent context doesn't save changes until you tell it to save.